# Has anybody ever got email in their doc saying they have funds from BTC Bitcoin bonus giveaway

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees, mining-pools, mining-theory

So I got an email from in my docs saying that I had to go to this page and I had all mining earnimgs everything that I hadn't withdrawed from a year ago on on a platform I let them use my IP to mine saying I have a bonus is this a scam or is it for real it's BTC Bitcoin bonus giveaway. I do remember somewhat going on a site and them using asking the question to use for Mining and me saying yes but I never heard nothing else about it I never went back in there so I don't know if it's from them or what but I will need to know if this is a scam or not

Comment: that's how scams work